# yadcf range_number_slider currency format

Tags: yadcf

I am using mvc aps.net, I get my data from the model, and when formatting the table I assign the currency format as follows:

```
<td class="centertext">
                @Html.Encode(item.AMOUNT.Value.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us")))
            </td>
```

Trying to use a range_number_slider filter as follows,  is unsuccessful.

```
        {
            column_number: 5,
            filter_type: "range_number_slider"
        }
```

The filter does not appear, if I remove the currency format it works perfect.

Is there a way to do it with the currency format?

Answer (score 0):

With Version:     0.9.4.beta.45

https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/src/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js

And this:

```
       {
            column_number: 5,
            filter_type: 'range_number', ignore_char: '\\,|\\$'
            
        }
```

Works perfectly!